# GnuRadio alternative for Selector Block

Tags: gnuradio

Hi I want to switch between tx and rx in a flow graph with my HackRF.
I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YTSI--d2UvQ) that shows how it could be done.
The key component is the Selector block which is now deprecated.

**Is there a alternative way to the selector block method?**

I also found [this](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/issues/195) feature request. But the last comment is nearly 2 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a QT GUI Chooser as an alternative to the Selector Block when you want a tx/rx switch. The two multiply blocks (not counting the volume control) gate the transmit and receive signals.
This image is also available at https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/File:Selector_demo.png

[image: Transmit/Receive switch]

Comment: I think thats not a solution to my question? What the Selector Block does is "Reroute" the flow graph  based on a given Variable Value. What that does in the example given in the Video is: It basically switches between the actual Signal and a null Sink/Source. I think what you want me to do is to use an actual Radio and drive PTT through a GPIO?

Comment: @maxbit89 I think this will do what you want.

Comment: I just found out that there is a replacement selector block https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/pull/2483. It has been incorporated into 3.7 and 3.8